# Windows Server 2008 what is the proper way to export or backup security event log

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows-event-log

Using WEVTUTIL.EXE to export the Windows Server 2008 Security event log, I get a permission problem (I have administrator privileges):

`c:> wevtutil epl security test.evtx`

"Failed to export log security. Access is denied."

I'm trying to write a script to backup and clear the Application, Security, Setup and System event logs.  The Security log is the only one giving problems.  How do I backup and clear it?  I would like to know the "proper" way to do this, because I don't want to upset the security people (auditors, forensics, etc).

Comment: Setup a tool to forward all the events via the syslog protocol to a server that collates your logs?  Adjust your log settings to only keep the last few days? - What kind of problem are you having that makes you think you actually need to purge this log?  Manually clearing this log is almost never required.

Comment: @Zoredache We want to keep archives of those logs, stored on a network share drive.  I'm not familiar with the first option you mentioned, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either by using Group Policy or the local policy on the machine, go to

```
Computer Configuration -> 
  Administrative Templates -> 
    Windows Components -> 
      Event Log Service -> 
         [Application|Security|Setup|System]
```

And configure the setting "Back up log automatically when full."

> This policy setting controls Event Log behavior when the log file
>   reaches its maximum size and takes effect only if the "Retain old
>   events" policy setting is enabled.
>
> If you enable this policy setting and the "Retain old events" policy
>   setting is enabled, the Event Log file is automatically closed and
>   renamed when it is full. A new file is then started.
>
> If you disable this policy setting and the "Retain old events" policy
>   setting is enabled, new events are discarded and old events are
>   retained.
>
> If you do not configure this policy setting and the "Retain old
>   events" policy setting is enabled, new events are discarded and the
>   old events are retained.

Then all your script needs to do is periodically harvest the directory for archived event log files and transfer them to your network share.